# how to inverse my formula in bitwise xor to get the value of 53?

Tags: bitwise-xor

This is my formula in hex. 
`(53+3C+7-1)xor (45+9B)` 
And the result of this formula is : `75` <-- hex 
My problem is I need to get `53` back using another formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some pseudo-code:

```
int startValue = 0x53
int resultValue = (startValue + 3C + 7 - 1) xor (45 + 9B)
int initialValue = (resultValue xor (45 + 9B)) - 3C - 7 + 1
```

so, you just xor the same 45+9B and reverse other operations (+ and -)